# Multithreading in Julia only one thread working

Tags: multithreading, julia

In the following code just one thread is working although I have 4 threads

```
a = zeros(10)
println(Threads.nthreads())
Threads.@threads for i = 1:10
           a[i] = Threads.threadid()
end
println(a)
```

Output:

```
4
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Why is this? It worked a few days ago and I can't remember that I changed anything.

Comment: Which version are you on? It works for me on 1.2.0: `julia> println(a) -->
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0]`. Perhaps there is just too little to do for each thread so that the compiler decides it is more efficient to just do everything on a single thread. No point in switching. Try to add more work inside the loop.

Comment: I am using 1.2.0 too. This is just a minimal example, my actual problem is much more complicated and I suspected that it doesn't multithread anymore and the above example confirmed my guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting Julia it works again.